# regex по букве и цифре

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть разные строки но надо определить именно L1H3708 и L1H2708. Необходимо определять c помощью rejex есть ли L на первом месте и 3 или 2 на пятом. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex: `^(L)(\w{2})(3|2)`

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что происходит?

Ищем слово, начинающееся с буквы `L`, после которой идет 2 *любых* печатаемых символа и после них 3 или 2